# Action delay extension method not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, extension-methods, action, task

I'm trying to create a handy extension method to Action to basically run that action after a delay: So far my extension looks like this

```
    public static void DelayAction(this Action DelayedAction, int millisecondDelay, CancellationToken Token)
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(millisecondDelay); }, Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);            
        t.ContinueWith(_ => DelayedAction, Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

I have a function I call that in turn uses these extensions

```
    private void DelayTask(Action ActiontoDelay, int millisecondDelay)
    {
        ActiontoDelay.DelayAction(millisecondDelay, _TokenSource.Token);
    }
```

Which I call like this:

```
    DelayTask(() => { _SomeFunction(SomeArgs); }, 1500);
```

But it all seems to drop down a whole and the action never fires. Where am I going wrong?

Edit 17-11-11 2300hrs:

I removed the generic extension method as it's not relevant to this example.

Also posting comment here as it doesn't format the code clearly in comments

If instead of the call

```
DelayTask(() => { _SomeFunction(SomeArgs); }, 1500);
```

I do this directly:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(1500); }, Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default); 
t.ContinueWith(() => { _SomeFunction(SomeArgs); }, Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

It works ok (sorry if there's any syntax error there I have done it from memory) So I beleive my issue is in the handling of the Action which Nick Butler's Answer eludes to

Comment: You haven't given us any context in terms of what sort of app you're running, etc. Could you give a short but complete example demonstrating the problem? See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: To invoke `Action<T>` you need an instance of `T` to be passed as argument, I can not see it in your code snippets

Comment: Are you sure you have a `SynchronizationContext`?

Comment: Sll sorry the Action<T> was just confusing the issue so I removed it. The issue is how to delay an action without the use of a timer (which I know I can use but I am trying to be consistent and use Tasks where possible)

Comment: @JonSkeet - The context in this instance is a state machine built on top of a VB 6 event model and in response to certain events raised by this model I wish to defer the next action for a period of time. Essentially I am just trying to mimic a timer callback delay using tasks and I figured I could do so by extending the Action type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your continuations are returning the `DelayedAction` delegate, not invoking it:

```
t.ContinueWith(_ => DelayedAction(), Token, ...
```

Comment: We have a winner! And I'm a loser for forgetting the brackets :)

Answer (score 3):

If Tasks is not a strong requirement I would suggest use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) which has built in "delay" feature, constructor looks like:

```
public Timer(
    TimerCallback callback,
    Object state,
    int dueTime,
    int period
)
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7.aspx):

> **dueTime** Type: System.Int32 The amount of time to delay before callback is invoked, in milliseconds. Specify Timeout.Infinite to
>   prevent the timer from starting. Specify zero (0) to start the timer
>   immediately.

**!** Also what is important you can change this delay after the construction stage.

---

```cs
public static void DelayAction<T>(
            this Action<T> delayedAction, 
            T argument, 
            int millisecondDelay, 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Timeout.Infinite to disable periodic signaling.
            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
                                {
                                   cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                                   delayedAction.Invoke(argument);
                                }, 
                                null, 
                                millisecondDelay, 
                                Timeout.Infinite);                        
        }
```

Comment: I like it, simple and it works, although I didn't implement this I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it with tasks. The problem was, that you called StartNew of TaskFactory, which immediatley starts your task.

Try it in this way - this should work:

```
public static void DelayAction<T>(this Action<T> DelayedAction, int millisecondDelay, CancellationToken Token)
{
    var task = new Task(t => { Thread.Sleep(millisecondDelay); }, null, Token);
    task.ContinueWith(t => DelayedAction, Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    task.Start();
}
```

Comment: It is my understanding and experience that the StartNew actually posts a message to the queue and it wont start immediately. If I am wrong and have by unhappy coincidence so far been lucky, please let me know!